# js: Is it possible to name a variable with a generated name?

Tags: javascript, variables, coordinates, dynamically-generated

*// For example:*

`coordinates_x = 1;`
`coordinates_y = 1;`
`x = eval ( "block_" +coordinates_x + "_" + coordinates_y );`
`var x = 0;`

*// So that there is the variable called* `block_1_1` *with the value* `0`

Comment: The best answer we can give: No, don't try to do this...

Comment: This is what arrays are made for.

Comment: @JJJ : I asked because i need a generator which will generate every block in a 100x100 field as a variable with value of 0 .  I will defenetly not type it by hand XD

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what arrays are made for.